# Why did Grama get furious when Mike won the game?

Tags: plot-explanation, rounders

Warning, spoilers ahead!

In the movie [*Rounders* (1998)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0128442/) towards the end when Mike wins the game which he plays against Teddy KGB, Grama gets furious and smashes the table. I can't see an in universe explanation for his fury. He was going to be paid anyways and he was mostly patient and to some degree friendly to Mike unlike his attitude towards Worm. I find it very hard to explain his reaction as him rooting for Teddy KGB. What's your take on that?

Comment: To be fair, Grama didn't "get furious and smash a table".. he simply lifts and turns over a chair, and then sits back down.. the seemingly loud sound from Grama's action comes from some the poker chips on the table falling over.

Answer (score 3):

Because of Teddy KGB's patronage.

Grama was a very low street criminal/hustler until KGB took him in and backed him.  Previously he was not worthy of respect, but as one of KGB's people he receives respect and fear.  Crossing or any level of disloyalty to KGB would likely end in death.  So income, respect, power, and Grama's life all depend on pleasing KGB.

So fiend or not he had to act that way.